# Is there really no way to get the current pathname in Next 13 SSR page, without using the middleware?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

For the last few days I'm playing with the Next 13 app directory, I just can't get beyond the problem, that there is no way to get the current pathname in a SSR page.

Yes I know, you can use middleware, you can use 'use client' and use the router. But for this case I need to get the pathname in a SSR page without using those 2.

Any idea ? Thanks